# What is the best and most comprehensive JavaScript graphing and plotting API?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I really want something that is eye catching and modern. I like how Digg does the Digg swarm (http://labs.digg.com/swarm/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at flot; **http://code.google.com/p/flot/**. You can check out some pretty cool-looking implementations of flot, [here](http://code.google.com/p/flot/wiki/FlotUsage).

> Flot is a pure Javascript plotting
>   library for jQuery. It produces
>   graphical plots of arbitrary datasets
>   on-the-fly client-side.
>
> The focus is on simple usage (all
>   settings are optional), attractive
>   looks and interactive features like
>   zooming and mouse tracking.
>
> The plugin works with Internet
>   Explorer 6/7/8, Firefox 2.x+, Safari
>   3.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Konqueror 4.x+ with the HTML canvas tag (the excanvas
>   Javascript emulation helper is used
>   for IE).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at

- http://raphaeljs.com/

> a small JavaScript library that should simplify your work with vector graphics on the web. If you want to create your own specific chart or image crop and rotate widget, for example, you can achieve it simply and easily with this library.

I don't know if it is *the best*.

Answer (score 1):

[Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) is an option.

Edit:

The team behind Protovis has since created [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), so this is likely a better option than Protovis.